# Custom xtick label in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to customize the xtick label in my subplots. I want to have xtick label only in the bottom x axis of my last plot (the fourth one with the first one being the topmost). My attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplots(4, 1)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.subplot(411)
plt.xlabel('x (h)')
plt.ylabel(' y1 (nT)')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = False
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.subplot(412)
plt.xlabel('x (h)')
plt.ylabel(' y2 (nT)')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = False
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.subplot(413)
plt.xlabel('x (h)')
plt.ylabel(' y3 (nT)')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = False
plt.plot(x,y3)
plt.subplot(414)
plt.xlabel('x (h)')
plt.ylabel(' y4 (nT)')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True # I thought it will enable xtick labels only on the bottom x-axis of the last plot
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = False
plt.plot(x,y4)
plt.show()
```

x, y1, y2, y3 and y4 are arbitrary arrays. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`sharex` keyword argument](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). If set to `True`, each subplot of a figure will have the same properties. Additionally, tick labels only go to the bottom subplot.

The `tight_layout` commands is just an easy way to arange the subplots nicely in the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, (4, 10))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 6))

for i, (ax, data) in enumerate(zip(axs, y)):
    ax.plot(x, data)
    ax.set_ylabel('y{}(nT)'.format(i+1))

ax.set_xlabel('x(h)')
fig.tight_layout()
```